# Vertical align in menu

Tags: html, css

My menu structure is

```
 <div id="menu">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#"><span>Two Words</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>Three Words</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>Very Long menu item</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>Short word</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>item5</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>item6</span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Menu has fixed width 720px and fixed height 50px. How can i make menu items to be like on this image?
[image]

here is my CSS

```
#menu {width:720px; height:50px; }
#menu ul {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#menu ul li {display:inline; float:left; margin-left:1px;}
#menu ul li a {display:block; width:119px; height:100%;}                
#menu ul li a span {display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;
background-color:gray; text-align:center; font-size: 14px; width:100%;}
```

Comment: Do you want the `li` to always expand evenly to fit the 720px width?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: Looking into display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; should get what you are after.

Comment: i added my CSS code. with code i can't get items to have vertical alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a headstart:

```
#menu {
    border: 1px solid #0000ff;
    padding: 10px;
}

ul li {
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sqva3/3/)

Comment: it is definitly what i was looking! Thank you. is it IE 6/7 friendly?

Comment: Prob not due to `display: table-cell;`. But you may be able to use a hack to get it to work for them.

Comment: i found only one hack for IE 6/7 but it uses <br> between long words. in my case it isn't good solution.

Answer (score 0):

use the text-align="center" in the span tags that you have created or do the same using css.